# Is it necessary to addIndex() on Setup Script?

Tags: magento-2.1, setup-script

I'm writing a setup script for my new module. I found that there are many setup scripts in `InstallSchema.php` contains `addIndex()`. But after I found some info on W3School, seems it's just a performance issue. So my questions are:

1. Is it a must to add index on my table?
2. What's the difference in terms on performance between with index or without index inside Magento?

Comment: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-an-index/